# How to display data in a row in Nopcommerce ..MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nopcommerce

The below code lists a set of product variants as a list  from top to bottom...how can i show this in a a row i.e horizontally

```
@foreach (var variant in Model.ProductVariantModels)
{   
   var dataDictVariant = new ViewDataDictionary();
   dataDictVariant.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = string.Format("variant_{0}", variant.Id);
   @Html.Partial("_ProductVariantLine", variant, dataDictVariant)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new template, something like `_ProductVariantItem` that renders the html with appropriate CSS classes to present them inline instead of as block items.